# Angular9 - Angular 2 component for szimek/signature_pad is undefined

Tags: angular

I'm trying to get this signaturePad to work. 
when I'm trying to instantiate it I get undefined. The module works on angular 8 or Less, 
I beleive it may have to do with ES6 compatibility. 
Does any one know a fix for this issue ?

here's my code snippet (very striagt forward)
app.ts ==>
...

```
import { BidiModule } from '@angular/cdk/bidi';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
import { SignaturePadModule } from 'angular2-signaturepad';




@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    HomeComponent,
    BpensiaComponent,
    BmngComponent,
    BindiComponent,
    BpartComponent,
    BuniqComponent,
    BlogComponent,
    AboutusComponent,
    JoinformComponent,

  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    BidiModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    SharedModule.forRoot(),
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    SignaturePadModule,
```

joinForm.ts ==>

```
import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild  } from "@angular/core";
import { SignaturePad } from 'angular2-signaturepad/signature-pad';


@Component({
  selector: "app-joinform",
  templateUrl: "./joinform.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./joinform.component.scss"]
})
export class JoinformComponent implements OnInit {
  @ViewChild(SignaturePad, {static:false}) signaturePad: SignaturePad;
   signaturePadOptions: Object = { // passed through to szimek/signature_pad constructor
    'minWidth': 5,
    'canvasWidth': 500,
    'canvasHeight': 300
  };

  constructor() {}

  ngOnInit(): void {}

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    // this.signaturePad is now available
    this.signaturePad.set('minWidth', 5); // set szimek/signature_pad options at runtime
    this.signaturePad.clear(); // invoke functions from szimek/signature_pad API
  }

  drawComplete() {
    // will be notified of szimek/signature_pad's onEnd event
    console.log(this.signaturePad.toDataURL());
  }

  drawStart() {
    // will be notified of szimek/signature_pad's onBegin event
    console.log('begin drawing');
  }
```

Tnx in advance

Comment: Hey are you getting any specific errors? Also, what version of the library are you using? Is it compatible to 3.6? As in Angular 9, the support for TS 3.4 & 3.5 has been dropped.

Comment: I'm getting {this.signaturePad is undefined}. versions   "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^9.1.2",
    "@angular/cdk": "^9.2.1",
    "@angular/common": "~9.1.2",
    "@angular/compiler": "~9.1.2",
    "@angular/core": "~9.1.2",
    "@angular/forms": "~9.1.2",
    "@angular/material": "^9.2.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~9.1.2",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~9.1.2",
    "@angular/router": "~9.1.2",
    "@babel/compat-data": "^7.9.0",
    "angular2-signaturepad": "^2.11.0",
    "rxjs": "~6.5.5",
    "tslib": "^1.10.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.10.2"

Answer (score 8, accepted):

According to the Github repository issues, there is some compatibility issues of this library with Ivy(New rendering engine of Angular 9)

The fix for your problem is replace the following line in your component(joinForm.ts).

```
import { SignaturePad } from 'angular2-signaturepad/signature-pad';
```

with

```
import { SignaturePad } from 'angular2-signaturepad;
```

This will resolve the issue and the `this.signaturePad` object will be available in `ngAfterViewInit()` function